# Neo4j csv data ingestion nodes getting replicated

Tags: python, csv, neo4j

I'm trying ingest a csv file into neo4j. I was able to add the properties correctly but when I create the relationships, the nodes are getting duplicated. The cypher query that I'm using

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///column_meta.csv" AS csv
CREATE (a:db { db_name: csv.table_schema})
CREATE (b:table {table_name: csv.table_name})
CREATE (c:column {col_name: csv.col_name, col_desc:csv.col_comment})

MERGE (a)<-[:belongs_to]-(b)
MERGE (b)<-[:has]-(c)
```

Here the nodes and relationships are getting created but each of them separately whereas I'm looking at creating interdependent relationships like db_name->table_name->col_name. Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`MERGE` can create data uniquely globally (with a constraint) or in the context of an existing node

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///column_meta.csv" AS csv
MERGE (a:db { db_name: csv.table_schema})
MERGE (a)<-[:belongs_to]-(b:table {table_name: csv.table_name})
MERGE (b)<-[:has]-(c:column {col_name: csv.col_name})
ON CREATE SET c.col_desc=csv.col_comment
```

Make sure to create a constraint on  `:db(db_name)`
And indexes on `:table(table_name)` and `:column(col_Name)`

Answer (score 0):

Try following this example:

```
--Load Order
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///TestFolder//Order.csv' AS line
WITH line
Merge(O:OrderInformation{name:line.orderID,orderID:line.orderID})
Return Count(*);

--Load Customer
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///TestFolder//Customer.csv' AS line
WITH line
Merge(C:Customer{name:line.customerName,customerID:line.customerID,customerName:line.customerName})
Return Count(*);

--Load Order and Customer Relationship
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///TestFolder//Order.csv' AS row
WITH row
MATCH (O:OrderInformation {name:row.orderID}), (C:Customer {customerID:row.customerID})
//now create a relationship between them
CREATE (C)-[:ORDERS]->(O);
```

Hope it helps!

Regards,
Vishal